# How can I mount a windows drive in Java?

Tags: java, windows-services, unc

We are working with some legacy code that accesses a shared drive by the letter (f:\ for example). Using the UNC notation is not an option.  Our Java wrapper app will run as a service, and as the first step, I would like to map the drive explicitly in the code. Has anyone done this?

Comment: If this is for 'users', consider picking a letter towards the end of the alphabet that won't get made unavailable by having one or two usb devices plugged in.

Comment: Thats good advice.  USB devices take the first available.  In our case, the letter of choice is out of our control.  We just need to get it mapped.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Consider executing the DOS command that maps a network drive as in the following code:

```
String command = "c:\\windows\\system32\\net.exe use f: \\\\machine\\share /user:user password";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
...
```

See details on net use command:

```
The syntax of this command is:


NET USE
[devicename | *] [\\computername\sharename[\volume] [password | *]]
        [/USER:[domainname\]username]
        [/USER:[dotted domain name\]username]
        [/USER:[username@dotted domain name]
        [/SMARTCARD]
        [/SAVECRED]
        [[/DELETE] | [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]]

NET USE {devicename | *} [password | *] /HOME

NET USE [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]
```

Comment: What happens if the user has already mapped f:? What happens if we run the same program a couple of times and kill it in the middle (e.g. during debugging session)?

Comment: If the user has already mapped drive f: you would get the "System error 85 has occurred." in the process output. You can just scan for it.

Comment: After the mounting, we can perform operations on the directory using normal FS commands right? Can you add an example to read a file? When I do `Path share = Paths.get(new URI("f:\"));` i get an error Provider "f" not installed.

Comment: Deprecated since jre18, what now?

Answer (score 11):

You can use JCIFS

http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/api/jcifs/smb/SmbFile.html

or if you want higher level API and support for other protocols like FTP, Zip and others:

http://commons.apache.org/vfs/filesystems.html

Both options are pure Java and cross platform.

Answer (score 5):

I think the easiest way is to use the Runtime.getRuntime().exec() method and call the "net use" command.

For example:

```
    try {
        // Execute a command without arguments
        String command = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\net.exe use F: \\\\server\\share /user:user password";
        Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

Comment: Directly using net.exe does not handle error cases and is not platform neutral.

Comment: @munsingh: He asked for Windows. Who cares for cross platform