# Connecting to password protected UNC using Java

Tags: java, passwords, java-native-interface, credentials, unc

I need to copy files to and from some windows network share, like \\compname\admin$ for example.
Right now we use JNI and open a connection using WNetAddConnection2 and then WinAPIs CopyFile to operate.

Source machine has Windows OS.

Isn't there another simpler Java way?

Comment: See this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208839/how-can-i-mount-a-windows-drive-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/) is an Open Source client library that implements the CIFS/SMB networking protocol in 100% Java.

Answer (score 0):

A solution we have involves the j-interop library and WMI.  May be worth a look.  However, we are coming from Linux copying to Windows.  I don't know what platform your source is from the question.

Comment: The source is a Windows machine.