# Java, JFileChooser & Windows Network Shares WITH Password Protection

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, windows-share

I need to present to the user or my application a dialogue in which that point to a particular file so naturally the easiest choice is to use a JFileChooser.

However the file that needs to be selected is on a Windows network drive/share but it is mapped to a drive on the host computer running my app. The network share IS password and JFileChooser does present the drive in its dialoge but it cannot browse the drive until I use another program e.g. Windows Explorer to view the network share where it will ask for the password.

Is it possible for the JFileChooser to request the user for a password? Does JFileChooser receive notification from the system that password/authentication is required? Using the Sun example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html), it just fails silently which is NOT what I want to happen. I want the user to be prompted for a password. Can I do this?

Comment: If you don't find a solution in the standard file chooser, you might craft your own based around [FileBro](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui).

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I'll keep that in mind however I cam across the Java class FileSystemView and might see what I can do with this.

Comment: The alternative (without browse button) would be to use drag-and-drop. That would be acceptable if there were some tree view to drop into (more than one choice to place the file). Did you try Java 7?

Comment: You might use the awt FileChooser.

Comment: Java 7 is probably out of the question due to the SDK available (I have not control over it) and drag-and-drop would work but would like to avoid it if possible. thanks for your comments though.

Comment: You could try running `net use …`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/208877/230513), although I'd prefer `ProcessBuilder`. You'd also have to critically examine the security implications.

Answer (score 1):

[PasswordAuthentication](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/PasswordAuthentication.html) may come in handy in this case.. Example can be found [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/javanetPasswordAuthenticationPasswordAuthenticationStringuserNamecharpassword.htm)

Comment: Interesting. I shall look into this for sure