# Pull a file from remote location (local file system in some remote machine) into Hadoop HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have files in a machine (say A) which is not part of the Hadoop (OR HDFS) datacenter. So machine A is at remote location from HDFS datacenter.

Is there a script OR command OR program OR tool that can run in machines which are connected to Hadoop (part of the datacenter) and pull-in the file from machine A to HDFS directly ? If yes, what is the best and fastest way to do this ?

I know there are many ways like WebHDFS, Talend but they need to run from Machine A and requirement is to avoid that and run it in machines in datacenter.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to achieve this:

1. You can pull the data using scp and store it in a temporary location, then copy it to hdfs, and delete the temporarily stored data.
2. If you do not want to keep it as a 2-step process, you can write a program which will read the files from the remote machine, and write it to HDFS directly.

   [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724576/read-remote-file-in-java-which-needs-username-and-password) along with comments and answers would come in handy for reading the file while, you can use the below snippet to write to HDFS.

   ```
   outFile = <Path to the the file including name of the new file> //e.g. hdfs://localhost:<port>/foo/bar/baz.txt

   FileSystem hdfs =FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://<NameNode Host>:<port>"), new Configuration());
   Path newFilePath=new Path(outFile);
   FSDataOutputStream out = hdfs.create(outFile);

   // put in a while loop here which would read until EOF and write to the file using below statement
   out.write(buffer);
   ```

   Let buffer = 50 * 1024, if you have enough IO capicity depending on processor or you could use a much lower value like 10 * 1024 or something

Comment: It is usual 2 step process and this is what I want to avoid. I want to copy it directly from remote machine to HDFS, but the program/script should run in cluster machine and not in remote machine.

Comment: This would run in the cluster machine and not remote machine, and is the easiest way out. Why do you want to avoid 2-step process ? Is there some specific use-case ?

Answer (score 1):

Please tell me if I am getting your Question right way.
1-you want to copy the file in a remote location.
2- client machine is not a part of Hadoop cluster.
3- It is may not contains the required libraries for Hadoop.

Best way is webHDFS i.e. Rest API