# How to list files from sharedDirectory?

Tags: java, file, jcifs

I tried below code for access network shared directory.But it worked if credentials not needed.

Once i have to pass the credentials it may be worked.

But i don't how to pass credentials for sharedDrive in following code.

```
File f = new File("//hostname/sharedDrive/Folder");

         // returns pathnames for files and directory
File[]  paths = f.listFiles();
```

Anyone suggest me way to access folder with credentials in java without using external libraries?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724576/read-remote-file-in-java-which-needs-username-and-password

Comment: @SajithSilva,I need to list out files from folder but that link contains passing filename added with folder specification.So it's not duplicate

Answer (score 0):

use with constructor for NtlmPasswordAuthentication

```
NtlmPasswordAuthentication ntlmAuthentication =
       NtlmPasswordAuthentication(domain, username, password);
SmbFile newFile = new SmbFile("smb://hostname/sharedDrive/Folder",ntlmAuthentication);
```

or directly

```
SmbFile newFile = new SmbFile("smb://hostname/sharedDrive/Folder",
       new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("", username, password));
```

or (if no password needed)

```
SmbFile newFile = new SmbFile("smb://hostname/sharedDrive/Folder",
       NtlmPasswordAuthentication.ANONYMOUS);
```

Comment: I should not use external libraries. Any other solution?