# Read a file from shared location with access restrictions (java)

Tags: java, security, networking, credentials, java-io

I have a program that has to read a file from network location - something like this

```
String sFileSource = "//MyShared/location/fileName.txt" ;
File inputFile = new File(sFileSource);

try {
    ffBuffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));           
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) { // should never happen
}
```

Now, the problem is that that shared location is on the different network domain and accessible only using domain credentials
How can I embed entering the credentials into this java program ?  The problem is that when ran from different PCs it fails due to login.

Answer (score 0):

Reading a file like that is not a secure way to do it, because you will expose your user domain credentiels.
Reversing the java app could lead to that, so it's better to use an ftp server for that.

The way I have done it before:

[Read remote file in java which needs username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724576/read-remote-file-in-java-which-needs-username-and-password)

Comment: Thanks.  No problem with FTP.  I already made a version of the code to do that.  Unfortunately, setting that location as an ftp site might be not possible for our organization. .. :(

Comment: I see, you can create a user in the same remote machine and give it limited access.
Then use SMB protocole to acces remote machine files, there is a Java Library to make that easy for you [https://github.com/AgNO3/jcifs-ng]