# Reading remote Ubuntu directory using ssh in java?

Tags: java, file-io, ssh, remote-access, smb

I want to read the content of a remote directory using `java`.

The directory is on a machine running Ubuntu. Right clicking on the folder should give the share folder option and its installed samba client for windows sharing, but I don't have any machine running Windows.

I'm looking for a **java api library** to access the remote directory content?

User will only provide username, password, ip and folder name.

eg `[//172.17.0.1/sharefolder/demo/]`

Thanks.

Comment: I think here it needs to be specified whether it is for SFTP or SAMBA within the title and question body.

Answer (score 1):

**For a Samba Share:**
Even SAMBA shares in linux use the same protocol as windows shares. 
So the post here can help: [How can I mount a windows drive in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208839/how-can-i-mount-a-windows-drive-in-java)
Basically, you could mount the shared location as a network drive using "net use" command .
You could call this either through windows console, or through a java Process.

**For a SFTP location:**

If you don't have a problem with calling/using an external command you could use sshfs (either out of java or through Process) to mount the remote directory into a local folder.

See: http://numberformat.wordpress.com/2010/03/01/how-to-mount-a-remote-ssh-filesystem-using-sshfs/

If you want pure java on how to access SFTP,I read that a library called JSch can be used to access SFTP directly from java. See:

- http://chrisjordan.ca/post/15052396308/java-sftp
- http://jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java.html

**If it's another type please specify**

Comment: Thanks for useful link. But i'm looking for JAVA based API to pass user and system info, then access the directory without mounting. I have founded few APi such as sshj , JCFS etc. But all of them are using secure FTP [get or put] for files.

Comment: Hi, thanks! Question, the protocol your using is SFTP, Samba, or another one?

Comment: SFTP, can we traverse all the file and folders ? Check, whether it is directory or not?

Comment: If you mount it within a folder then it will look like as if it is part of the file system, so you will be able to traverse. Java sees what the operating systems tells it.

Comment: Is there any code to mount the remote directory using ssh and java programming interface?

Comment: You could call sshfs using Runtime.getRuntime().exec and spawn a new process to do the mount. If you want pure java on how to access SFTP,I read that a library called JSch can be used to access SFTP directly from java. See: 
http://chrisjordan.ca/post/15052396308/java-sftp
http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27784/discussion-between-menelaos-and-a-p-s)

Answer (score 0):

You might find the [The Java CIFS Client Library](http://jcifs.samba.org/) having the API you need - it is useful for both server and client.

Here is an example taken from their documentation to retrieve a file:

```
import jcifs.smb.*;

jcifs.Config.setProperty( "jcifs.netbios.wins", "192.168.1.220" );
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("domain", "username", "password");
SmbFileInputStream in = new SmbFileInputStream("smb://host/c/My Documents/somefile.txt", auth);
byte[] b = new byte[8192];
int n;
while(( n = in.read( b )) > 0 ) {
    System.out.write( b, 0, n );
}
```

Comment: Does JCIFS lib allow to read directory content, even if entire cluster is Ubuntu machine only? Secondly can we use ssh to do the same process in java?

Comment: It appears that you are wanting an sftp-based API not SMB/CIFS. You should edit the question to reflect that accordingly. At any rate, hopefully the answers that Menelaos will help you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For SFTP consider using JSCAPE's [Secure FTP Factory](http://www.jscape.com/products/components/java/secure-ftp-factory/). Documentation with code examples can be found [here](http://files.jscape.com/sftp/docs/html/index.html?overview16.html).

Answer (score 0):

[jsch-nio](https://github.com/lucastheisen/jsch-nio) is a fully functional unix/linux java FileSystemProvider over ssh.