# Windows7 Batch file: Net Use command

Tags: java, security, networking, batch-file

I have a team of users that have *read only* access to a shared network drive. Sometimes these users will need to deploy their project resources to the drive. I am trying to come up with a secure build process for them to use. Currently I am using a batch file that they can execute from their local system which will do the following...

1. User starts batch file
2. Batch file calls a java program (the credentials are 'hidden' and 'encrypted' within the java program)
3. The java program handles the encryption process and then calls a final batch file that actually runs the NET USE command to map the drive with admin credentials
4. The final batch file maps the drive, copies the required resources onto the shared drive, and then re-maps the drive with original user credentials (read only).

My major problem is that users will have direct access to the batch files that do this entire process and they could simply remove the @ECHO off command from the final batch file to display all the credentials to the cmd output window.

I'm not sure if there's a better solution to this sort of thing? Any ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Also, all machines are using Windows 7 and using a Windows network drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution would be to copy the resources directly in the Java program using the [jCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/) library.

A second option would be to map the drive from within the Java program.  There's more information in this SO question: [How can I mount a windows drive in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208839/how-can-i-mount-a-windows-drive-in-java)

Comment: I was able to include the batch file within the jar file. This way when I invoke the executable.jar file, no contents are output except for exactly what I want. Network secure! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are some .bat to .exe compliers out there.  Not sure how well they will work for your particular batch file, but probably worth a look.  You can search for them.  Here's a couple of them out there

[Advanced BAT to EXE Complier](http://battoexeconverter.com/)

[Quick Batch File Compiler](http://www.abyssmedia.com/quickbfc/)

[Batch File Complier PE](http://www.bdargo.com/)