# passing password using process builder not working for "net use" command

Tags: java, command-line, processbuilder, net-use

I am trying to run the "net use" command by invoking it using process builder. As I pass the password to  the OutputStream using PrintWriter it fails with the following error : 
*System error 1219 has occurred.
Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again.*

**I have checked the username, password and the command, by running it manually. Its working fine**

The code snippet :

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("net","use","\\\\<SERVERNAME>\\<SharedLocation>","/USER:<username>","*");
Process p = pb.start();
OutputStream out = p.getOutputStream();
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(out);      
writer.println("<pwd>".toCharArray());
int exitCode = p.waitFor();     
System.out.println("Exit Code :"+ exitCode);
```

Comment: Able to solve this case ? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions:

- Run `net use * /delete /y` as your first step to remove all connections before you start. You can also try removing specific connections.
- Use a pure Java solution instead of `net use` -- see https://stackoverflow.com/a/208896/4803

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I used `net use */delete /y` to remove all the connections which also removed the connection for which I was trying `net use`. Now it is failing with a different error :
_System error 86 has occurred.
The specified network password is not correct._ 
But I when manaully run the command from cmd with the same password it passes successfully. Is my way of passing the password incorrect?

Comment: Your code works for me. There are some other code samples in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208839/how-can-i-mount-a-windows-drive-in-java?lq=1 that you could try.

Comment: Have you use the same way to pass the password that I have used in the code?Becuase I tried running the code from my friend's system.I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I literally just signed up on stackoverflow because I had the exact same issue and solved it after spending hours and hours of trial and error.

The solution for me was adding a "\" (respectively "\\" in java code) right before the username.

This is what worked for me:

```
String[] cmdCommand = new String[]{"net", "use", "\\\\" + pcSystem.getIpAddress() + "\\c$", "/user:\\" + pcSystem.getUsername(), pcSystem.getPassword()};
Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(cmdCommand).start();
```